# ReactJS - Multiple ways to add/modify propTypes of a stateless functional component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

## The Question

How come **Approach 2** below works?

## High Level

I've recently come across two different ways of defining a stateless functional ReactJS component (both works fine):

- **Approach 1:**

  1. `const Greet1 = function () {...}`
  2. `Greet1.propTypes = {...}`
  3. `export default Greet1`
- **Approach 2:**

  1. `Greet2.propTypes = {...}`
  2. `export default function Greet2 () {...}`

Approach 1 makes sense to me: we start by defining `Greet1`, then add/modify its properties.

Approach 2 is the one I don't get. How is it possible that we are allowed to add/modify a property within `Greet2` before `Greet2` itself is defined?

(Or is it more a JavaScript fundamental basics instead of ReactJS specific?)

## Detail Example

Say I have a ReactJS `GreetContainer` that wraps the individual presentational components `Greet1` and `Greet2`.

### GreetContainer

This is `GreetContainer.js` - a (can-be-made-stateful) Container Component that wraps  Presentation Components:

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react'
import { Greet1, Greet2 } from 'components'

const GreetContainer = React.createClass({
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <Greet1 message="This is Greet1"/>
        <Greet2 message="This is Greet2"/>
      </div>
    )
  },
})

export default GreetContainer
```

### Greet1

This is `Greet1.js` - a (stateless) Presentational Component (that I understand):

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react'

const Greet1 = function ({message}) {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{message}</p>
    </div>
  )
}

Greet1.propTypes = {
  message: PropTypes.string.isRequired
}

export default Greet1
```

### Greet2

This is `Greet2.js` - a (stateless) Presentational Component (that I don't quite understand - it doesn't make sense to me to specify `Greet2`'s properties before `Greet2` itself is defined?):

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react'

Greet2.propTypes = {
  message: PropTypes.string.isRequired
}

export default function Greet2 ({message}) {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{message}</p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

## Updates - on JavaScript Hoisting

The answer provided below suggests approach 2 works because JavaScript uses Hoisting by default (to hoist declarations to the top of code).

Despite this default behaviour, [W3Schools JavaScript - Hoisting](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp) says it is good practice to declare  variables before using them. So I've created `Greet3` (tested and worked) - which I guess might be a better pattern than `Greet1` and `Greet2`.

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react'

function Greet3 ({message}) {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{message}</p>
    </div>
  )
}

Greet3.propTypes = {
  message: PropTypes.string.isRequired
}

export default Greet3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In javascript function declarations are [hoisted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function#Function_declaration_hoisting) to the top. So in actuality javascript treats this:

```
Greet2.propTypes = {...}
export default function Greet2 () {...}
```

like this:

```
function Greet2 () {...}
Greet2.propTypes = {...}
export default Greet2;
```